# Несколько экземпляров одной формы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Необходимо вызывать множество экземпляров одной формы в приложении, то есть при такой реализации

```
ProcessInfo.PropertyProcess StartForm = new ProcessInfo.PropertyProcess();
StartForm.Owner = this;
StartForm.Text = dataGridView4.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
StartForm.Show();
StartForm.MainMethod(dataGridView4.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString(), dataGridView4.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString(), dataGridView4.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString());
```

он у меня запускает несколько форм, но все динамические данные переменных обрабатываемые в формах(Chart,backgroundWorker, множества Label) становятся равными во всех формах последней запущенной, за то статистические данные обрабатываются корректно, как запустить экземпляр формы с разными данными динамического типа, дайте хотя бы ссылочку.

Основные переменные:

```
private static string[] ArrayProperty = new string[13];
private static string Information = string.Empty;
private static string Name = string.Empty;
private static double ResultIOMax = 100;
private static double ResultIOIntetval = 0;
private static Image ImageTables;
```

и единственная глобальная переменная, не перезаписываемая в этой форме(только чтение)

```
MainForm.ValueProcessInfo.DataStatisticOld.Rows[i]["DataGraph"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поля, отмеченный `static`, являются общими для всех экземпляров класса. Если вам нужно чтобы каждый экземпляр формы имел свой набор полей - просто уберите `static`:

```
private string[] ArrayProperty = new string[13];
private string Information = string.Empty;
private string Name = string.Empty;
private double ResultIOMax = 100;
private double ResultIOIntetval = 0;
private Image ImageTables;
```

Comment: Пойду читать маны дальше